# Run specific Python script (created with Model Designer) when pushing a button in Qt Designer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qt-designer

Let me start by saying my Python knowledge is very, very limited.

I created three models using the Model Designer in QGIS, and exported them as python scripts. Then I used the Plugin Builder and Qt Designer to create the following plugin:

[image]

Ideally after clicking each button, I'd like for its respective model/Python script to be executed, just as if I'd touched the run button from the Model Designer. I've been following a general tutorial and then searched around a bit but I can't figure it out.

Is there an easy way to do it?

I've found that with

```
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function)
```

I can link the button to a function, so I'm wondering if somehow I can easily convert the model into a single function I can call this way.

This is my plugin just in case: https://shorturl.at/vCKM8. The model's scripts that I want to link to the buttons are c1.py, c2.py and c3.py.

Honestly, if the solution is really complicated for someone unfamiliar with Python, I'll probably just drop it. I already have the three models that I can open and easily run from the Model Designer; this plugin is just for convenience's sake to have everything together.